# Month entry each for the years specified

Tags: node.js

I need the code for the following output.I tried somany times but failed to find.
This is the format of  output which I want

```
{
name: "Jan",
ds10: 0,
ds9: 0,
ds8: 0,
ds7: 0,
ds6: 0,
ds5: 0,
ds4: 0,
ds3: 0,
ds2: 0,
ds1: 0
},
```

This is a code to find the number of times the month coming in between the years 2004 and 2013.
ds1 to ds10 happens is the difference of two years.If we increase the years the "ds" range comes according to that difference.
That is

```
ds1: corresponding to 2004
ds2: corresponding to 2005
ds3: corresponding to 2006
```

This is only an example case of month January.

I wrote the code like this .

```
app.get('/stats-by-time', function(req, res){
  var year    =  (req.query["year"]) ? req.query["year"] : "";
  var year2     =  (req.query["year2"]) ? req.query["year2"] : "";
  var family    =  (req.query["family"]) ? req.query["family"] : "";
  var month     =  (req.query["month"]) ? req.query["month"] : "";
  var eventDate     =  (req.query["eventDate"]) ? req.query["eventDate"] : "";
  var errFlag   =   1;
  var errObj    =   '';
  var filter    =  (req.query["filter"]) ? req.query["filter"] : "";
  //var filter =  req.query["filter"] || {};
  try {
    filter = (filter != '') ? JSON.parse(filter) : {};

    } catch(err) {
      errObj = err;
      errFlag = 0;
    }
  var callback = req.query["callback"] || '';
  var yearvalues = {};
  yearvalues["year"] = year;    
  if(year !="year" && year2 != ''){

    var objyears = { $and: [ { "year" : { $gte: year } }, { "year": { $lte: year2 } } , filter ]  }
    collection.aggregate(

      { $match  : objyears},
      { $group : {
        _id : '$month',
        //month : '$month',
        count : { $sum : 1 },

      }},

      { $sort : {_id: 1}},
      function(err, results) {
        var outputArray = [];
        for(var j in results) { 
          var obj1 = {};
          var objyear = results[j];
          obj1["name"] = objyear['_id'];
          //obj1["ds"] = ""+ objyear['count'] +"";

          obj1["ds"] = objyear['count'];
          var diff = year2 - year;
          console.log("difference",diff);

          outputArray.push(obj1);

        } 
        console.log("results",outputArray);
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        if (callback != '') {
          res.end(callback + '(' + JSON.stringify({success: true, rows: outputArray}) + ')');

        } else {
            res.end(JSON.stringify({success: true, rows: outputArray}));
        }
      });   
  } else {
  res.end(JSON.stringify({success: false, error:{msg:"Year2 must be passed"}}));
  }
});
```

Comment: what you have tried post your code..

Comment: @shylendra I posted my code.Could you please have a look?